# Saving and retrieving text typed into a textbox in a Firefox addon

Tags: firefox, xul

I'm just now getting used to using XUL. I've created a preferences window (options.xul) with just a text box:

```
 <textbox id="api" preference="link-target-finder-api"/>
```

But I'd like to save the text entered here and access it. How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a XUL [textbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textbox):

```
<textbox id="hello-world" value="Hello, world!"/>
```

Comment: @InBetween - OK. In that case, you could use a preference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Preferences